# What is the best way to power a 90v DC motor?

Tags: batteries, dc-motor

I have a 90v 22amp electric motor, I want to use it to make an electric scooter, what is the best solution for a power supply. I've looked at using an inverter, but I then get insufficient amperage. I would like the battery to be as small as possible, but this is rather difficult because of the high power needs of the motor. Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think Tony Stark used some round flat glowing thing about the size of a deck of cards. But as they're fictional, you need to use a battery of sufficiently size. LiPos are about the best easily obtainable power to size and energy to size ratios, pick a sufficiently large one of those, or several in series for 90v.

Comment: As you will learn, the hard way, there's **always** a compromise. I don't think you want a battery "*as small as possible*", because running the scooter off a coin cell battery will make the scooter run for a fraction of a second. Get serious with some proper requirements.

Comment: Have you researched the voltage most electric scooters use? And where and why did you choose a 90V motor? Well, you can try and copy the Vectrix which retails apparently for $10k... 125V and what do you think you will spend to make one?

Comment: 2kW on an electric scooter? Holy moly, it will accelerate you to dangerous speeds very quickly. Really, you only need about 1/4 of that for having a bike+driver accelerate to more than 50km/h.

Answer (score 2):

You need enough batteries connected in series to add up to 90 volts plus an electronic speed control (ESC) unit. Without the ESC, the motor will draw a lot more than 22 amps for a short time every time you switch it on. It will try to accelerate to full speed as fast as it can. That will be hard on both the motor and the battery and could destroy both very quickly. The ESC will limit the current and control the acceleration.

You could use a lower battery voltage and a boost DC to DC converter, but then the battery current will be higher than the motor current. You may or may not be able to find such a thing.

90-volt motors are usually intended to work with an ESC that takes a 120 volt AC input. Some such controllers may accept either AC or DC input. A 90-volt ESC rated for DC input may be difficult to find. You might be better off looking for a lower voltage motor.

Answer (score 0):

Look at high-powered electric RC airplanes.  Some of them use induction motors which they drive with a 3-phase flux vector drive (i.e. A 3-phase AC inverter).   The battery packs and power output is about what you're after.   The voltage is low, *but it's high-frequency AC*.

You could set the inverter for one frequency and wind a transformer (or 3) to kick the voltage up to your motor's voltage at that frequency. Then rectify to DC and voila.